# Silverlight get row from value

Tags: c#, silverlight-4.0

I have a `List<Customers>` and I need to find the row in a datagrid that contains the Customer's ID and change the background color.

How do I achieve this using Silverlight 4?

Answer (score 0):

In c#, you need to implement the `INotifyPropertyChanged` interface on your Customer object, then add a boolean `Selected` property.
In the XAML, use data binding to associate the row background color to the Selected property. You can achieve this either with triggers (that are limited in Silverlight compared to WPF) or use a converter:

```
<Grid Background="{Binding Selected, Converter={StaticResource BoolToColorConverter}}">
```

The converter is a IValueConverter class taking a boolean and returning a `SolidColorBrush`.